# Почему такая запись json является некорректной и как записать корректно

Tags: json

```
{
"1":"1",
"2":"2",
"3":"3"}
,
{
"1":"4",
"2":"5",
"3":"6"}
```

При попытке оформления перечисления в таком виде валидатор выдает ошибку.
Ругается на запятую и фигурную скобку между двумя массивами.
multiplie root JSON elements.
Как в таком случае правильно оформить массив?

Понятно, что я могу сделать как-то так:

```
{
"1": {
"1":"1",
"2":"2",
"3":"3"
}
,
"2": {
"1":"1",
"2":"2",
"3":"3"
}
}
```

Но нет ли корректного способа записи без пары "ключ"?

Comment: можно так `[["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"]]`

Comment: Вы как формируете строку?

Answer (score 1):

Я у вас массива даже не вижу. Можете сделать вот так, если я вас правильно понял

```
{
  "arr1": [
    {
      "1": "1"
    },
    {
      "2": "2"
    },
    {
      "3": "3"
    }
  ],
  "arr2": [
    {
      "1": "4"
    },
    {
      "2": "5"
    },
    {
      "3": "6"
    }
  ]
}
```

если же вам нужен именно массив. В данном случае доступ к 4 это array[1][0]

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```